# React Router Outlet and Protected Outlet does not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to render outlets based on user login state. The problem is the oulet never get rendered. Only parent element is rendered.I tried using "/:username/boards/*" for path. But that didn't work either.

App.js

```
<Route element={<ProtectedOutlet />}>
   <Route path="/:username/boards" element={<UserHome logOut={actions.logOut} getAllBoards={actions.getAllBoards} />} >
      <Route path="b" element={<Board />} />
   </Route>
</Route>
```

ProtectedOutlet.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ProtectedOutlet = () => {

  const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default ProtectedOutlet;
```

UserHome.js

```
const UserHome = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="user-home">
        <Navbar />
        <Outlet />
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-outlet-and-protected-outlet-does-not-working-vr6lkl) and the routes/outlets appear to function without issue. I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Uh, then may be i screwed up the code somewhere. The route always get redirected to "/:username/boards" even i type "/:username/boards/b" in url bar. But it works when i removed Protected Outlet and simply wrap the Board component with UserHome.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live? If you've hosted your repo in Github then it's possible to import the repo directly into a sandbox.

Comment: I can't it says there are more than 500 modules.

Comment: I see. Can you create a minimal codesandbox example then? Just a minimal code example that reproduces this issue that we can inspect.

Comment: Ok bro, I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I changed my codes in ProtectedOutlet

from

```
const ProtectedOutlet = () => {

const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn);

return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}
```

to

```
const ProtectedOutlet = () => {

const { isLoggedIn, user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

if (!isLoggedIn && !user) return <h1>Loading</h1>

return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}
```

And I've other route for unauthenticated routes like (/login,/register, etc..) called PublicOutlet.js.

PublicOutlet.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const PublicOutlet = () => {

const { isLoggedIn, user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

return isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to={`/${user.username}/boards`} 
replace={true} /> : <Outlet />;
}

export default PublicOutlet;
```

The problem is when I enter url in url bar, the protectedoutlet component check if the user is logged in or not. When it is rendered the first time, `isLoggedIn` state is not updated yet. so it get navigated to `/login` route. Then `/login` route is wrapped in publicoutlet component. When publicoutlet component check if the user is is logged in, `isLoggedIn` state changed to true. So, it get redirected to `/${user.username}/boards`. It took me 2days to find out the problem. LOL